# Angular Material component mat-select ngModel not persisting selected choice

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a select multiple using the Angular Material `mat-select` component. My options are displaying correctly in the dropdown but the selected values are not persisting to the UI. For example, on page load `locationNameSelectedItems` returns -

```
[{  
  id: 60  
  itemName: "Main Location - 1100 Superior Road"  
}]
```

- 

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="locationNameSelectedItems" formControlName="locationName" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let location of locationNameDropdownList" [value]="location.id">{{location.itemName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

How can I ensure that the correct selections are displayed?

Comment: When is it loosing the value of `locationNameSelectedItems`?

Comment: It doesn't lose it, there is never anything selected in the dropdown although the value of `locationNameSelectedItems` is correct.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz? Also I see you are using reactive and template driven together any reason for that ?